# Entity Framework paging and sorting is giving unexpected results

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm currently building a ASP.NET web app search result page. I've implemented different types of sorting for users but some of them are giving unexpected results.

These two line of code are executed regardless of the sort type or any other factors:

```
var resources = ctx.Resource.Where(p => p.CityAlias == city.ToLower() && p.Company.Hidden != true && p.State == 1);

FilterResources(ref resources, resourceTypeId, serviceId);
```

FilterResources:

```
private void FilterResources(ref IQueryable<Resource> allRes, int resourceType, int selectedService)
{
    allRes = allRes.Where(p => p.ResourceType_Id == resourceType && p.ResourceService.Any(x => x.Service_Id == selectedService));
}
```

*Resource.ResourceService is of type ICollection that is mapped to a database table of the same name with a foreign key pointing to Resource.Id*

So far so good. First a working sort example:

```
private void SortResourcesByName(ref IQueryable<Resource> resources)
{
    resources = resources.OrderBy(p => p.Name);
}
```

Then we handle paging:

```
int count = resources.Count();

var resourceList = resources.Skip((page - 1) * 10).Take(10).ToList();
```

**This set from entities seems to be correct and in the right order, but here's when things get weird:**

If we use a different sort, some of the pages have duplicate results and in some cases if I go through the pages, I can see duplicate (or more) Resources scattered across the list.

For example:

```
private void SortResourcesByPrice(ref IQueryable<Resource> resources, int serviceId)
{
    resources = resources.OrderByDescending(p => p.ResourceService.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Service_Id == serviceId).Price.Value)
        .ThenByDescending(p => p.Company.CompanyService.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ServiceId == serviceId).Price.Value);
}
```

If I use this sort, the first page of the view is correct, but when I start navigating to other pages, I start to see duplicate results.

**The query returns just over 200 results, which are divided among 21 pages. Pages 3 and 4 are exactly the same for some reason, pages 5 and 6 also yield same results. In these cases, ResourceService.Price = null.**

Bonus weirdness:
using OrderBy() instead of OrderByDescending does not give duplicate results

```
private void SortResourcesByPrice(ref IQueryable<Resource> resources, int serviceId)
{
    resources = resources.OrderBy(p => p.ResourceService.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Service_Id == serviceId).Price.Value)
    .ThenBy(p => p.Company.CompanyService.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ServiceId == serviceId).Price.Value);
}
```

I'm at a total loss here, so I'd really appreciate help. If you can't make sense of my example code or can't understand the question in some other way, I'd happily try to provide more information.

Edit:
I'd like to add that the amount of results/Resources is always the same, regardless of what sort I'm using (just as it's supposed to).

Edit 2:
Fixed some numbers & typos

Comment: Make a dump of resources with resources.ToList() in different step to show whate contains your resources and when the duplicate result appears

Comment: I made a dump and it seems like the results are mixed when paging is done (IE. resources.Skip(20).Take(10).ToList())

Comment: I think I fixed the problem by casting resources.ToList() before paging, IE. `resources.ToList().Skip(20).Take(10)`

Comment: Adding the ToList materializes all the elements so all the data (not only 10 records) get transfered from the server to the client. To understand the problem you can view the query that EF sends to DBMS just viewing the content of resources (the IQueriable). I think you could find a surprise about the behaviour of FirstOrDefault inside the order by.

Comment: You can use https://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/ to view the SQL generate by EF COPY and PAST result SQL QUERY here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/ to view the SQL generate by EF copy and paste the sql query directly in SQL Server Management studio and look where is the duplicate origine, you can change query to remove duplicate entry and after search Linq responsible.
You can put the SQL here too